# ECS Fargate batch job tasks via airflow waiting in pending state too long

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to run 1000 tasks in parallel. These are short running batch jobs that use the same taskdef (hence same container) with just the args being passed different (basically the arg passed is the value from 0 thru 999).
I used airflow to call the ECSOperator in a loop just as it is explained here:
https://headspring.com/2020/06/17/airflow-parallel-tasks/.
When I look at the 'Tasks' tab for my ECS cluster in AWS, I see the tasks queued up with a mix of PROVISIONING, PENDING and RUNNING.
The RUNNING jobs are just a handful - most of the tasks are in PENDING state which eventually go into RUNNING state.

Questions:

1. Why are most jobs in PENDING state ? what are they waiting for (like a limit on RUNNING jobs?) ? How can I check what it is doing during this PENDING state ?
2. Why are the RUNNING jobs just a handful ? How can I make most, if not all, tasks go to RUNNING state simultaneously ? Is there some limit on how many jobs can run simultaneously while using Fargate ?
3. The Services tab is empty - I have not configured any Services - isn't this meant only for long running jobs/daemons or can batch jobs like mine take advantage of it too (and reach the goal of getting all the 1000 tasks run at the same time) ?
4. I have not setup anything in the 'Capacity Providers' tab. Will that help in getting getting more tasks to run in parallel ?
5. I am not clear on the concept of autoscaling here - isn't Fargate supposed to provision the 1000 CPUs if need be so that all those tasks can run in parallel ? Is there a default limit and if so, how do I control it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much to unpack.

1-2: there is a TPS (tasks per second) provisioning throughput to be considered. We (AWS) are in the process of documenting better these limits (which we don't do today) but for 1000 tasks consider that it can be expected to take "a few minutes" to have ALL of them in RUNNING state. If you see them taking "hours" to get to RUNNING state then that's not normal. Also note that each account/region has a default [concurrent task limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-quotas.html) of 1000 (which is not to be confused with the throughput with which you can scale to 1000 concurrently running tasks).

3: No. As you said that's just for control loop so that you can say I always want to run n tasks (or DAEMONS) and ECS will do that. You are essentially using an external control loop (Airflow) that manages the task. This won't have any influence on the throughput.

4: No (or at least I don't think so). You may try if Airflow supports launching tasks using CPs instead of the traditional "launch type" mode.

5: the autoscaler (in the context of Fargate) is pretty much an ECS Service construct (see point #3). There you basically say "I want to run between n and m tasks and scale-in/out based on these metrics". And ECS/Autoscaling will make the task count fluctuate based on that. As I said you are doing all this externally launching tasks individually. If Airflow says "launch 1000 tasks" there is no autoscaling... just a rush to go from 0 to 1000 (see #1 and #2).

Comment: 1-2. I see that it definitely takes more than a hour for all the jobs to get into a RUNNING state. Of the 1000 tasks, about 8 get into PENDING state, about 4 in RUNNING and about 10 in PROVISIONING _at a time_. I think most of the jobs are 'queued'. Why would that be ? Is there any info I can give that you can help me troubleshoot ?  
3. Just for clarification, the 'Services' tab is essentially meant for deamons right ? (ie not for short running batch jobs)

Comment: 4. So how does one use Capacity Providers with batch jobs ? (based on your answer).   
  
5. Thanks - this makes sense. A general question on autoscaling: doesn't it lose time to provision new CPU's while up-scaling ?

Comment: 1-2 how long is "at a time"? the batching you describe makes sense to me but I'd expect a frequency of the "at a time" of a batching like that to be "a few seconds" and not "a few minutes". If you want to speed this troubleshooting up you should probably open a ticket. 3. Daemons AND long running tasks (e.g. start a web service backed by 3 tasks and keep them up).

Comment: 4 CPs are orthogonal to the type of workloads you run (one off tasks or services). CPs are just a way to source capacity. It's just a different syntax you use in how to launch your tasks. This is more important for running them on EC2 than for running them on Fargate

Comment: 5. Yes but you do not need to think about autoscaling in the context of running 1000 tasks one off. You need to think about it in the context of "I have a service that needs to have between 2 and 10 tasks, adjust it based on actual usage" (at low load you will have 2 tasks at super high load you will have 10 - and everything in between)

Comment: 1-2: By 'at a time', I mean, any time I come back and look at the ECS tasks that are running (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/v2/clusters/<myclustername>/tasks), that is what I see: About 20 tasks listed. As these tasks get completed, fresh tasks get added in that list with about the same mix of statuses. I was expecting this: 1. All the 1000 tasks are listed in PROVISIONING status (since airflow invokes the ECSOperators in a loop with just the arg value changing) 2. and then when I refresh the ECS UI after a few mins, all (or most) of them RUNNING simultaneously.

Comment: 3,4,5: Thanks for your explanations - am able to understand this better. Is there any documentation that goes over different use cases/examples and the recommended ECS solutions ? Like: UseCase1: For short running batch jobs of 1000 tasks: CPs not necessary, 'Services' not necessary, use Fargate; UseCase2: For long running batch jobs, use xyz configuration; UseCase3: For deamons/web services, use xyz configuration (load balancer + service etc.) etc. I see a lot of 'how' to do things and not so much of 'when' and 'why'. Sorry if such documentation is available and I have searched well enough.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion on opening a ticket - I am planning to open a ticket to get focussed help with my situation explained above if you (understandably) cannot go beyond a certain point in helping me fully resolve this - will wait to hear from you on the above comments first.

Comment: (In the 1-2 above, the reason I saw 20 tasks listed at a time is because of the page setting. But the question remains as to why all tasks don't end up in running state and there is a mix of status until the very end)

Comment: The ticket is the best way to go because the support team will have visibility on what happened on the infrastructure (tasks timing etc) and will have more context to draw conclusions.

Comment: As far as docs are concerned there are some explanations in the ECS docs for when using [one off tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html) and when using [services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html). There is also trible knowledge in various blogs ([example](https://exanubes.com/blog/ecs-tasks-vs-services)).

Comment: I think we are hitting a "where is the mess hall?" situation here :) (reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N16YkjFVAyE&t=163s)

Comment: Thanks for the doc links and your answers. As you suggested, I will look into writing a ticket to get into specifics. I see what you're saying about the 'mess hall' :D  . Thanks for all your responses.